# Connection time out access the external IP google compute engine

Tags: go, google-compute-engine

I'm new in GCP environment and tried to create go running on VM. External IP is 35.247.137.122.

below is the go code, giving response `code:200, message: "OK"`

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("ready to dig in...")
    http.HandleFunc("/", handle)

    fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":8989", nil))
}

func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    m, _ := json.Marshal(struct {
        Code    int
        Message string
    }{
        Code:    200,
        Message: "OK",
    })

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte(m))
}
```

When I run the go files, I can get the response from the internal sources [image: here].

For the external test, set the firewall rules [image: here] but I still got the connection time out when access the [external](http://35.247.137.122:8989)
Anybody willing to tell me how to resolve the issues
Thanks.

nb: I already installed nginx, so access the external IP will result in nginx home, but I tried to access my go code without Proxy Pass from nginx.

Comment: do you mean you can access the external IP if  you set nginx  listening on 8989,

Answer (score 0):

What you did is exactly what's needed in order to achieve what you asked for. 
I've tried reproducing exactly what you've got and I've received a 200 OK from the server on the given port on the external IP.

Probably it was a temporary problem, or maybe there is another firewall rule blocking the one you need. Try lowering the "Priority" number, in order to raise the rule's priority.